# Prefix-less superscript in org mode

Tags: org-mode

I want to write «<sup>n</sup>P<sub>r</sub>» in org mode

Now org mode doesn't treat "^" as a superscripting operator  if its preceded by a space char. The best I could come up with was

```
\nbsp{}^nP_r
```

where there is a zero width space between the `n` and the `P`.

This is quite clunky. Is there any better way?

Comment: I don't know of a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Well for now `${}^nP_r$` works... sorta kinda...

The space between the "n" and the "P" is too much

So I am doing `${}^n\!P_r$`

Comment: You can shave off a few characters with: `${^n}P_r$`. For such formulas exported to PDF, org passes the code to LaTeX for processing. So searching for how to do this thing in LaTeX might get you better/faster answers.